# modify admin actions

Tags: django

How to modify default admin action "delete_selected"

Comment: Please specify how you want to modify it?

Answer (score 14):

[**`Action docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#)

delete selected:

> If you wish to override this behavior,
>   simply write a custom action which
>   accomplishes deletion in your
>   preferred manner – for example, by
>   calling Model.delete() for each of the
>   selected items.

This [**`discussion`**](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/956ca508fde69a7d) has an example of overriding 'delete_selected' for a model. It could be implemented like this:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['custom_delete_selected']
    def custom_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
         #custom delete code
    custom_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected items"

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(SomeModelAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin

You can write custom actions, so overwriting the delete_selected action will allow you to carry out whatever functionality you need (see the warning box on the top of the page which mentions overwriting the delete() action)

Answer (score 0):

DOC:[Disabling actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-actions)

Disabling a site-wide action

`admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')`

Otherwise override `ModelAdmin.get_actions`